# How do I set up Airflow DAG permissions to query a BigQuery table that is built on top of a Google Sheets doc?

Tags: oauth, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an Airflow DAG which schedules a set of BigQuery scripts (and some other steps). I would like one of my BigQuery tables to be based on a set of Google Sheet inputs that can easily be changed. Setting up a table based on a Google Sheet is easy enough, but if I do this I get an error in my Airflow job:

> Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason':
> 'accessDenied', 'location': '/gdrive/id/123....', 'message': 'Access
> Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file
> pattern.'}

I'm assuming I need to add some level of permissions for the Airflow job to access this Sheets file, but I'm not sure how. Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to the scopes in your Google connection. You can do this in the UI via Admin -> Connections.

see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html) for more information.